# Custom context path in external tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8

I made a Spring-Boot application that I want to run in an external tomcat 8.

In a Spring-Boot application , the context-path can be chosen using the property `server.context-path` in `application.properties` but as I am using an external tomcat 8, this property is not used.

Hence, I took a look at the [tomcat-8 documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html) which states:

> If you want to deploy a WAR file or a directory using a context path that is not related to the base file name then one of the following options must be used to prevent double-deployment:
>
> - Disable autoDeploy and deployOnStartup and define all Contexts in server.xml
> - Locate the WAR and/or directory outside of the Host's appBase and use a context.xml file with a docBase attribute to define it.

As I do not want to pollute `server.xml`, I chose the second option. Hence, I located the war in `/home/myuser/myapp/application-1.0.0.war` and I placed a context file name `application-1.0.0.xml` under `conf/Catalina/localhost`. This file contains only those 2 lines :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/myapp" docBase="/home/myuser/myapp"/>
```

I can see in the logs that tomcat8 starts successfully, the application appears to be deployed in the tomcat manager but :

- The path is `/application-1.0.0` instead of `/myapp`.
- Moreover, a directory `application-1.0.0` appears in the `work` directory but stays empty.
- The logs does not show any spring related logs as if the application had never been initialized.

**Note** : I know that the war is correct because it works if I place it in the `webapp` directory (with the default context path though).

**Note** : If I rename `application-1.0.0.xml` to `foo.xml`, the tomcat manager shows that the application is deployed under context-path `/foo` (but it is still never started).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer :

- Concerning the context-path, the attribute `path` of the context file is indeed ignored :

> This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.

- Concerning the `docBase` attribute, I misinterpreted the following sentence :

> Locate the WAR and/or directory outside of the Host's appBase and use a context.xml file with a docBase attribute to define it.

Actually, in `docBase`, I put the path to the directory which contains the war instead of the path to the war itself.

Comment: So what's the right configuration then? And - do you need to update the file each time you deploy a new version?

Comment: I need the answer too. Can you post the entire solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone, following (placed inside conf\Catalina\localhost\service-discovery.xml) works for me on on Tomcat 9

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/service-discovery" docBase="D:/Projects/codebase/apps/service-discovery/target/service-discovery.war"/>
```